# Vision product search: client.createReferenceImage method error "Error: 3 INVALID_ARGUMENT: Invalid image format"

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage, google-admin-sdk, google-vision

I created a cloud function that downloads an image from a giving url and uploads it to firebase storage

```
async function downloadImageJimp(fileId,imageUrl) {
        const image = await jimp.read(imageUrl);
        await image.resize(900, 900);
        return  image.writeAsync("/tmp/${fileId}.jpg");
   }
```

```
downloadImage(fileId,doc.data().imageUrl).then(val=>{
                            return bucket.upload(`/tmp/${fileId}.jpg`,{
                                destination: "my-destination-path",
                                gzip: true,
                                metadata: {
                                    metadata:{
                                        firebaseStorageDownloadTokens: uuidv4()
                                    }
                                }
                            }).then(val=>{
                                return bucket.file(`my-destination-path`).makePublic();
                            });
```

after the upload, a cloud function i wrote triggers this function

```
async function createImageReference(){
        try{
            const productPath = client.productPath(projectId, location,productId);
            const gcsUri=`gs://my-destination-path`;
            const referenceImageId=imageId;
    
            const referenceImage ={
                uri: gcsUri
            }
    
            const req = {
                parent: productPath,
                referenceImage: referenceImage,
                referenceImageId: referenceImageId
            }
            const [response] = await client.createReferenceImage(req);
            // console.log(`response.name: ${response.name}`);
            console.log(`response.uri: ${response.uri}`);
            return true;
        }catch(err){
            console.log(err);
            return false;
        }
    }
```

The createImageReference() function avove returns an error message "Error: 3 INVALID_ARGUMENT: Invalid image format" even thought the downloaded image is in jpg format. what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turn off gzip. If you want to keep down GCS usage, you could delete the image after import.

Comment: Turning off gzip solved the problem. Thank you for your help!!